# This Jquery Menu is Driving Me Nuts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, navigation

I'm using a jquery navigation menu that has the line follow when you hover over an element and highlights it. It works now, but I'm having a bunch of quirky issues that I can't figure out for the life of me.

I'll show you my code first and then explain the issues I'm having.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#nav2 li a').hover(function()
    {
        var offset=$(this).offset();
        var thiswidth =$(this).width()+13;
        $('#nav2 li.ybg').stop().animate({left:offset.left+12+"px",width:thiswidth+"px"},400,function(){
            $(this).animate({height:"28px"},150);
        });    
    },
    function()
    {
        $('#nav2 li.ybg').stop().animate({height:"4px"},150,function(){
            var offset=$(this).offset();
            $(this).animate({left:offset.left+40+"px",width:"55px"},600,'easeOutBounce');   
        });    
    });
```

});
Also, here is the DIV for the ybg if it helps:

```
ul.nav li.ybg { background-color:#5222B4; position:absolute; z-index:50; width:55px; height:4px; margin-top:6px; }
```

The main problem is that when you move your mouse off of the menu it stops where it is and shrinks instead of going back to the left most item (Home).

There are other quirks but I'm hoping that if I can figure this out I'll be able to work out the rest.

Hopefully that makes sense (the URL is www.buildagokart.com if you want to see what I'm talking about - it's just a random URL I'm using to test).

Answer (score 0):

```
...
        $(this).animate({ left: "0px", width: "55px" }, 600, 'easeOutBounce');   
...
```

Comment: The problem is that goes ALL the way to the left of the screen instead of back to where Home is. I want it to go back to Home, but it's in a different place in different size browsers...

Comment: how about `$(this).parent().css('left') + 'px'`?

Comment: That sounded like it would work...the concept seems right, but it's still doing the same thing...

Comment: I need to see your HTML markup and CSS, try and put together a simple jsFiddle and I'll see if I can figure it out for you.